How to create a QR code in SAP Build apps
I'm currently working on a project I'm trying to generate a QR code with a given input data by the user from what I tried from what I tried so far is that API don't work and I cannot use require from what I tried at least if anyone has some experience with SAP Build apps and knows how to use an API like qrcode.js etc. or has a clue for a solution I'd be glad to hear it.
Well as already explained I tried calling an API I also tried using require but none of my tried attempts has led to any actual useful result nor show worthy.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
